# Nodemailer SMTP Server receives e-mail but doesn't respond anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, smtp, nodemailer

I have got a simple script for receiving e-mails, even though it receives e-mails and prints ok, unfortunately, doesn't respond to sending server, (no 250OK) as a result sending server keeps sending the same e-mail (retrying)

What is required to respond or what might be wrong?

In this setup, this code running in my local network (OsX), my router's port 25 forwarded to my machine.

```js
const SMTPServer = require("smtp-server").SMTPServer;
const parser = require("mailparser").simpleParser

const server = new SMTPServer({

  onData(stream, session, callback) {
    parser(stream, {}, (err, parsed) => {

      if (err){
        console.log("Error:" , err)
      }
      
      eMailParse(parsed)
      stream.on("end", callback)

    })
    
  },
  disabledCommands: ['AUTH']

});

server.listen(25, "192.168.50.20")

console.log("Mail Server Running");


function eMailParse(parsed){
    const {headers, from, to, cc, date, html, text, messageId} = parsed;

    console.log("\n//############# New Mail #############\n")
    console.log(messageId)//Unique Mail ID;
    console.log("\n//$$$$$")
    console.log(from)
    console.log(to)
    console.log(cc)
    console.log(date)
    console.log(text)
    console.log("//====")
    console.log(html)
}
```

Gmail's response

> The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7720 [dc-133a13304d09.*******.fun. nn.nnn.nn.nn: timed out]

Telnet response

> 421 Timeout - closing connection
> Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious, isn't an SMTP server for sending out emails? The email client connects to the SMTP server, transmits the email, and the SMTP server sends it out. To receive an email from Google I'd think you need an IMAP server instead. Something like [wildduck](https://github.com/nodemailer/wildduck)

Comment: Well actually it is correct, but it receives e-mails and I can't say I understand exactly what is going on. In an article it says "An SMTP receives emails from other email servers or email clients"

Comment: What I understand is; it is working as a relay, so, takes e-mail and sends somewhere else, and it should return the answer of the relayed mail server, but instead of relaying I'm intercepting e-mails and I want to return 250 answers to transmitting server.

Comment: Yeah, according to [this](https://www.duocircle.com/content/smtp-as-a-service/smtp-server) the smtp server apparently accepts the email initially, then forwards it to the imap/pop server. Anyway, I can't really help with this, sorry :)

Comment: It is most likely that by the time that you register the "end" listener (`stream.on("end", callback)`), that the "end" event has already occurred. Thus the callback is never made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while, I tried a while more and I've found the solution.

This part is not working

```
eMailParse(parsed)
stream.on("end", callback) //on("end") is never triggered
```

Instead;

```
eMailParse(parsed)
callback()
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently. I found this thread and the answer worked for me too, but later I found the real problem - the listener for the 'end' event should be attached immediately in onData callback, not in the parser callback. Here's the solution:

```
const SMTPServer = require("smtp-server").SMTPServer;
const parser = require("mailparser").simpleParser

const server = new SMTPServer({

  onData(stream, session, callback) {
    stream.on("end", callback)
    parser(stream, {}, (err, parsed) => {
      if (err){
        console.log("Error:" , err)
      }
      
      eMailParse(parsed)
    })
  },
  disabledCommands: ['AUTH']
});

server.listen(25, "192.168.50.20")

console.log("Mail Server Running");


function eMailParse(parsed){
    const {headers, from, to, cc, date, html, text, messageId} = parsed;

    console.log("\n//############# New Mail #############\n")
    console.log(messageId)//Unique Mail ID;
    console.log("\n//$$$$$")
    console.log(from)
    console.log(to)
    console.log(cc)
    console.log(date)
    console.log(text)
    console.log("//====")
    console.log(html)
}
```

Comment: The issue with placing `stream.on("end", callback)` at the top is that you cannot respond to the client with an error message. If your parser fails in some way so that the incoming email is not correctly parsed, then the client will not know that it should retry sending.


So yes, this "works", in the sense that the 421 error goes away, but the functionality is incomplete, since the server should be able to return an error `callback(err);` if one occurs.

Answer (score 0):

By the time that you register the "end" listener using `stream.on("end", callback)`, the "end" event has already occurred. Thus that event listener is never triggered, and the callback is never made.

This is because the callback function in `parser(stream, {}, callback_fcn)` (see also comments in the code below) is called *after* the parser has finished consuming the stream (or after an error has been raised). Thus at the point where we enter the function body of `(err, parsed) => {\\function body}`, the stream has already ended. And at the time that we register the "end" listener by executing `stream.on("end", callback)`, the "end" event has already occurred, so the listener will never trigger.

```
  onData(stream, session, callback) {
    parser(stream, {}, (err, parsed) => {
      // at the point where we enter this function body of the parser
      // callback function, the stream has already terminated
      if (err){
        console.log("Error:" , err)
      }
      eMailParse(parsed)
      // this will have no effect because the "end" event 
      // occurred before the listener was registered
      stream.on("end", callback) 
    })
  },
});
```

Your eventual solution works because you are now calling the callback *after* the parser has finished (and thus the stream is ended).

The best approach should also call `callback` as
`callback(null, "Success message")` or
`callback(err)`, possibly setting the `err.responseCode` appropriately, in the case of an error in parsing or otherwise.